# Cross domain request to fetch Google Maps's SDK

Tags: google-maps, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am using service works to prefetch Google Maps Javascript SDK. Because service workers use `fetch` I keep getting this error -

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

How do I enable CORS on google maps SDK?

*UPDATE*

I am using [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox) and in my service worker I have the following code —

```
import toolbox from 'sw-toolbox'
      toolbox.precache([
        '/',
        '/bundle.js',
        '/manifest.json',
        '/ola_icon.png',
        '/favicon.png',
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myapikey&callback=initMap'
      ])
```

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

There's some documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors#using-cors) about accessing Google APIs using CORS.